# Azure Storage - File on Public URL

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files

I am using Azure Storage to save some files. I want these files to be publicly available on a temporary basis. Currently, I'm saving them via an azure storage file service. Each file is give a URL of the structure ./[file-share]/[directory]/[file-name].[ext].

My question is, is there a way to make this URL publicly available? I do not see a way. If there isn't, is there some recommended way to make a file public available? I do not see a way to do this via a file service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to make this URL publicly available?

One possible solution would be to create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` on the file in question with at least `Read` permission and share SAS URL with your users. You mentioned that you want the file to be publicly available on a temporary basis and for that SAS would perfectly fit the bill. You can set the SAS expiry based on your needs and once the SAS token expires, the file will no longer be available.

Other option would be to use `Blob Storage` instead of `File Service`. Here not only you can use Shared Access Signature but also change the container's ACL. By making the container's ACL as `Blob`, the blob (file) will be publicly available.

Comment: I switched to Blob storage because I ran into a limit to the number of file shares I can do with Files.